# UnityProject\Packages\com.unity.test-framework\UnityEngine.TestRunner\Files could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've just downloaded and installed the newest version of Unity (2019.2.3f1) and integrated my Visual Studio into the project for script editing. However I can't attach any scripts to Unity because of the title error. Do I need to perform some additional setup or include extra dependencies to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Is it in Visual Studio only ? Unity Editor also have this error ?

Comment: @TimChang it's in Visual Studio only yes, when I run from Unity Editor it compiles and I can see the changes made in the script. However, this means I cannot debug in Visual Studio due to not being able to Attach To Unity

Comment: @LewisSeddon It's look like visual studio refrence problem , so you can delete all `".csproj" ".vs" ".sln"` all vitual studio file , And refresh your unity editor , let unity create a new visual studio setting file.

Comment: @LewisSeddon sometimes it could slove the problem , you can try it.

Comment: @TimChang Unfortunately that didn't work!

Comment: @Ruzihm It's a bunch of CS2001 errors, one example is:
Error CS2001 Source file 'E:\Projects\Project\Packages\com.unity.test-framework\UnityEngine.TestRunner\AssemblyInfo.cs' could not be found. UnityEngine.TestRunner E:\Projects\Project\CSC

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: @Ruzihm VS Community 2017

Comment: @LewisSeddon I'm seeing [some people have success with a similar problem](https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-building-project-with-visual-studio-in-unity-2018-unity-package-source-file-not-found-error.530766/) by updating visual studio (some from 2017.x to a more recent 2017.y; some from 2017.x to 2019.z). Try updating to community 2019. Let us know if that helps you

Comment: @Ruzihm Updated the 2017 version and it's worked. Thanks a lot for your help! If you can make this an answer I will accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard to pin down bug, but in general, people have seen success when they update to a more recent version of Visual Studio.

Update to a newer version of VS 2017 or update to a recent version of VS 2019.